# Split list for punctuation

Tags: python, regex, list, file, split

I have a given title

I want to  start splitting on whitespace and punctuation of a list, so that no word in the resulting list contains any whitespace or punctuation character.

Ex: the word "Joe's" gets split into "Joe" and "s"
'ad sf' gets split into 'ad' and 'sf'

Starting:

```
['Toms', 'ad  sf', "Joe's"]

Ending:
    ['Toms', 'ad', 'sf' , 'Joe', 's']
```

I have tried regex, split, but there's not an easy and concise way. Can anyone think of a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
s = ['Toms', 'ad  sf', "Joe's"]
final_result = [j for i in s for j in re.split(r'\W+', i)]
```

Output:

```
['Toms', 'ad', 'sf', 'Joe', 's']
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you can simplify your solution: `[j for i in s for j in re.split(r'\W+', i)]` - nested list comp idiom

Comment: I agree, why is this a -2?

Answer (score 0):

Split each item and join the pieces:

```
from itertools import chain
mylist = ['Toms', 'ad  sf', "Joe's"]
list(chain(*[re.split("\W+", item) for item in mylist]))
#['Toms', 'ad', 'sf', 'Joe', 's']
```

Here's a "clean" functional solution:

```
list(chain(*map(lambda item: re.split("\W+", item), mylist)))
#['Toms', 'ad', 'sf', 'Joe', 's']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin way to achieve what you want, but here is the most concise way I could think of using `map`.

```
import re

words = ['Toms', 'ad  sf', "Joe's"]

sum(map(re.compile(r'\W+').split, words), [])

# Output: ['Toms', 'ad', 'sf', 'Joe', 's']
```